# Snap multiple marker to nearest road

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I have a list of GPS points with which I create the path on the map according to the tutorial http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/route-between-two-locations-with-waypoints-in-google-map-android-api-v2/ . I would like to put these points as markers on the map to it were a road. I care about determining where the nearest point of the drawn path relative to the point that I have a GPS. How do I do this without causing each of the points of a new query to google directions api.